# No autocompletion on required classes in Rubymine

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I am requiring the `date` library and I would expect the methods from this library to appear in the code completion list (and hence get the documentation inline). However nothing appears. Why so?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What RubyMine and Ruby version are you using? Please try [4.5 Release Candidate](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP), everything works fine for me in that version